# What does python_qt_binding.loadUi's 3rd arg do in PyQt binding?

Tags: ros, pyqt, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, in rqt_bag `loadUi` takes a python dictionary as its 3rd arg [like this](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/groovy-devel/rqt_bag/src/rqt_bag/bag_widget.py#L65):

```
ui_file = os.path.join(rp.get_path('rqt_bag'), 'resource', 'bag_widget.ui')
loadUi(ui_file, self, {'BagGraphicsView': BagGraphicsView})
```

Now tracking back `loadUi`, what `PySide` binding does makes sense looking at [source code](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/blob/groovy-devel/src/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py#L199) -- it uses dictionary "as dictionary":

```
def loadUi(uifile, baseinstance=None, custom_widgets=None):
    from PySide.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
    from PySide.QtCore import QMetaObject
        :
        def createWidget(self, class_name, parent=None, name=''):
            # don't create the top-level widget, if a base instance is set
            if self._base_instance is not None and parent is None:
                return self._base_instance

            if class_name in self._custom_widgets:
                widget = self._custom_widgets[class_name](parent)
```

But what about [PyQt binding](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/blob/groovy-devel/src/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py#L148)?

```
def loadUi(uifile, baseinstance=None, custom_widgets=None):
    from PyQt4 import uic
    return uic.loadUi(uifile, baseinstance=baseinstance)
```

Just ignoring? If so, what's the purpose of letting `PySide` binding have 3rd arg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56382/what-does-python_qt_binding.loadui%27s-3rd-arg-do-in-pyqt-binding?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PyQt uses the "promoted classes" specified in the UI file and there does not need the 3rd argument.
PySide on the other hand does not support that, so you have to explicitly pass the mapping to the loadUi function.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-27**:
I see. Given that PySide requires the 3rd arg to incorporate custom classes, I think `python_qt_binding.loadUi` as an API should obligate the 3rd arg. I'll open a ticket.

**Comment by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) on 2013-02-27**:
This was certainly true for PySide 1.0.6, but has anyone checked if it changed in more recent versions?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-02-28**:
[Ticketed](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/issues/2). Let's move further discussion there.